# How do I set associate function to sequelize models with TypeScript (after "sequelize.define")?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

To define a model with `sequelize`, you can do something like...

```
const User = sequelizeInstance.define<UserInstance>(
  'users',
  { /* fields */ },
  { paranoid: true } // and other options, like scopes
);
```

The problem is that I don't see how I can define class methods for a model with TypeScript. It seems that `sequelize` 4 (?) allowed developers to put `classMethods` property as an option, but I'm using `sequelize v6` and `@types/sequelize v4`.

i.e.

```
export interface UserInstance extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>, UserAttributes {
  getRoles: BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<RoleInstance>;
  setRoles: BelongsToManySetAssociationsMixin<RoleInstance, number>;
}

const User = sequelizeInstance.define<UserInstance>(
  'users',
  { /* fields */ },
  { classMethods: { /* methods */} } // <= This is apparently deprecated
);

User.associate = (models) => { // TypeScript complains that associate doesn't exist
  User.belongsToMany(models.Role, { /* info about the pivot table*/ });
};
```

This option seems to be deprecated. Due to this, TypeScript is warning that `Property 'associate' does not exist on type 'ModelCtor<ModelInstance>'.ts(2339)`

Is there any alternative to define a class method (or, just the `associate` function)? I'm searching [the doc](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html), but can't find any information.

Any advice will be appreciated.

PS: I'm using TypeScript 4.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
type UserStatic = typeof Model
    & { associate: (models: any) => void }
    & { new(values?: Record<string, unknown>, options?: BuildOptions): UserInstance }

const User = <UserStatic>database.define('users', {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But this doesn't work :( (I'm using TypeScript 4.1.3, btw)

Comment: Here's the message: `Property 'associate' does not exist on type 'UserStatic'.ts(2339)`. This is from `User.associate = ...`

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, I renamed `association` to `associate` in my answer

Comment: working but where can i find the reference? no related example in the doc at all :(

Comment: `associate` is for a function to register associations and `{ new ... }` is just the same as a constructor for `Model` class: `constructor(values?: TCreationAttributes, options?: BuildOptions)`